# Node.js "require" - avoid duplicate running

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Short situation report:

I have 2 scripts which do a lot of API calls to exchanges.
Some calls (mainly balance checks) are identical on both scripts.

To limit the API calls, I have put all these duplicate calls in a third script, which puts that data in a file.

Script 1 and 2 both read from that file, and all is working well.

However,
to further reduce the overhead of filewrite and read every 3 seconds, I experimented with "require"

Script 1 now requires script 3, and the balance-array is passed along that way.

What I didn't expect, is that I don't need to run script 3 seperately anymore.
Upon starting script 1, Script 3 is apparently running in the background (and passes console.log messages along to script 1)

And now to get to the question:
If I put the same require in script 2, will script 3 effectively be running twice? That would defeat the whole purpose of the third script...

To be clear:
Script 3 is just one function, running in interval, without any input at all from script 1 and 2.
The balance array is the only export.

Comment: yes it will be running twice. any reason you just dont run everything at one script if they are related?

Comment: Both script communicate with 3 exchanges. Only 1 exchange is mutual.

Comment: Both scripts are over 700 lines, merging them would be crazy :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first time you `require` a file, it's evaluated synchronously - if it completes successfully (doesn't throw), its `module.exports` value is cached.

Further times you `require` that file, you get the cached exports value.

It sounds like what you want here is to have each file `module.exports = function something() { /* put your actual code here */ }` - then you can require that function, and invoke it only when you need to (and multiple times, if you need to).

Comment: No, actually there are no module.exports, or functions to be called from within the other scripts. script 3 was written to be a stand-alone polling script. it basically does the same API calls every 3 seconds. In each loop it gathers an array of numbers from an API call, and exports those 3 arrays via exports.name1 = Array1.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you convert the standalone scripts into standalone functions instead - that gives you more control over when to execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

Building off what @LJHarb wrote in his answer, since the file is only evaluated once, then the requests won't be duplicated unless you instruct them to. I created the following example :

```
// index.js
require('./module1');
require('./module2');

// module 1
require('./module3');

// module 2 
require('./module3');

// module 3 
console.log('process starting...');
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('interval executing...');
    // execute your requests here.
}, 3000);
```

From the cli :

```
# node index.js 
process starting...
interval executing...
interval executing...
interval executing...
```

You can see 'process starting...' was only logged once.

If you want more control over the flow of execution, you can use a module scoped variable to prevent something from happening more than once... update the above to the following :

```
// index.js
require('./module1');
require('./module2');

// module 1
const poll = require('./module3');
poll();

// module 2 
const poll = require('./module3');
poll();

// module 3 
let t;

module.exports = function poll() {
    if (t) return;
    console.log('process starting...');
    t = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('interval executing...');
    }, 3000);
}
```

... again you can verify the interval is only created once.

Note, **this will not work** in circumstances where you have multiple node processes or child processes. If you are operating in a browser and the same file is included twice, it will be evaluated twice with no concept of shared module scope!